# Multiple keywords search sql sentence not showing in Laravel8

Tags: laravel

I'm studying keyword search.
I successed single keyword search and now I'm trying to make multiple one.

as Half-width space keyword split.
I use this Middlewarefrom this website

https://qiita.com/logue/items/64c4b5545f76ef17de70

When I dd() . I can see keyword split are good.
but when I search function runs There is no sql sentence appear
and I can display empty result page.

Could you teach me correct code please?

> Controller

```
    public function order_adv()
    {
    $keyword = request('search_adv');

if(!empty($keywords)) {
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $products = Product::when('w_m','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
    }
}
     return view('products.result_adv' , compact('products'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

> WEB.php

```
Route::get('products/search_adv', [ProductController::class, 'search_adv'])->name('search_adv');
Route::post('products/search_adv', [ProductController::class, 'order_adv'])->name('products.search_adv')->middleware('keyword');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use where call back method

```
public function order_adv()
{
    $keywords =explode(' ',request('search_adv'));
     $products = Product::when(count((array)$keywords),function($query)use($keywords){
                $query->where(function($query)use($keywords){
    
                    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
                        $query->orWhere('w_m','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
                    }
                });
        })->get();
     return view('products.result_adv' , compact('products'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I use your code then I got this error ErrorException
Undefined variable: keywords  Could you show me the whole controller code please?

Comment: Dear @John Lobo Thank you very much! but I got same error that is ErrorException Undefined variable: keywords.

Comment: @bluetail so it should be $keywords = request('search_adv');  and updated answer also

Comment: Dear @John Lobo  Yes I was guessing it. so I changed as your update. but I got this error count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable.

Comment: is $kywords array or string ?.if it object then count((array)$keywords)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234679/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-bluetail).

Answer (score 1):

```
$keywords = request('search_adv');
    if (count($keywords) > 0) {
        $products = Product::where(function($query)use($keywords) {
                    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
                        $query->orWhere('w_m', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                    }
                })->get();
    }
```

In your case use where Clauses,
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

use when in condition statement,
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-when

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Is your code need ->middleware('keyword'); what I put web.php ?